# Getting item with most recent date in PostGreSQL

Tags: postgresql, datetime, filter

Suppose I have queried a table called items_run to get the following results:

```
object_id  item_id  run_date
    0       1010    8/1/2023
    1       1020    8/3/2023
    2       1030    8/4/2023
    3       1010    8/5/2023
    4       1020    8/6/2023
```

Here's the query:

```
SELECT object_id,  
       item_id,
       run_date
FROM items_run
WHERE run_date > '2023-07-30'
```

I want to adjust my query to select the rows with only the most recent run_date for a particular item_id. So it would look like this:

```
    object_id  item_id  run_date
       0        1010    8/5/2023
       1        1020    8/6/2023
       2        1030    8/4/2023
```

I have tried to add `WHERE run_date > '2023-07-30' AND run_date = (SELECT MAX(run_date) FROM items_run)`, but that just returned an empty table. How could I accomplish my goal here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple aggregate gives you exactly what you're asking for:

```
SELECT
    MIN(object_id)
    , item_id
    , MAX(run_date)
FROM items_run
WHERE run_date > '2023-07-30'
GROUP BY item_id
ORDER BY 1; -- first column
```

Comment: I went with this answer as it was the simplest way to get my desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this query and see if it works:

```
SELECT object_id, item_id, run_date
FROM items_run
WHERE (item_id, run_date) IN
  (SELECT item_id, MAX(run_date)
   FROM items_run
   WHERE run_date > '2023-07-30'
   GROUP BY item_id)
```

This should hopefully help you get the results you need.

Answer (score 1):

[`DISTINCT ON`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) gives you the latest per group. The most recent dates are in rows 3, 4 and 2. [Demo:](https://dbfiddle.uk/TNJV82c-)

```sql
select distinct on (item_id) *
from items_run
order by item_id,
         run_date desc;
```

| object_id | item_id | run_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1010 | 2023-08-05 |
| 4 | 1020 | 2023-08-06 |
| 2 | 1030 | 2023-08-04 |

If `object_id` in your output example was only supposed to be an ordinal number, then replace it with a [`row_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html):

```
select row_number()over() as object_id,
       * 
from (
    select distinct on (item_id) 
        item_id,
        run_date
    from items_run
    order by item_id,
             run_date desc
) as subquery;
```

| object_id | item_id | run_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1010 | 2023-08-05 |
| 2 | 1020 | 2023-08-06 |
| 3 | 1030 | 2023-08-04 |